# Prove that the alternating group $A_n$ contains $A_{n-1}$ as a subgroup $n$ times.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G= A_n$ be the alternating group and let $G_i$ be the stabilizer of $i$ in the natural action of $G$ on $i \in \{1,2,\ldots, n \}$ then $G_i \cong A_{n-1}$.

It is obvious that is enough to prove this for $G_1$ it's easy to prove that $G_1 \cong G_i$ for each $i$. I'm reading Dummit and this is a step to prove that $A_n$ is simple. The book says that proposition so casual that I think that it is trivial. But I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: $G_i\cong A_{n-1}$, not $A_{n-2}$.

Answer (score 4):

In effect $G_i$ is the set of permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,i-1,i+1,\ldots,n\}$ which are even. It's the set of even permutations of
an $n-1$ element set, so is isomorphic to $A_{n-1}$ as a permutation group.
Indeed, $G_n$ is in effect the set of even permutations of
$\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ so really, really **is** $A_{n-1}$.